# reverse_tcp not working with tor

Tags: tor, kali-linux, msfvenom

I have the following situation.

I have configured proxychain with tor. I collect my IP address (provided by tor)  from whaismyip_dot_com and set that ip as LHOST and used my localport as LPORT in msfvenom and payload option. I used reverse_tcp as my payload. till this point everything worked fine but when the victim is running the exe/apk, nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really work like that. I would recommend learning how computer networks work, and then learning how a Tor network works.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. May I get any specific solution?

Comment: The IP address you got from whatismyip was the IP of a Tor exit node. Tor exit nodes only accept connections from the Tor network. The exit node doesn't do anything with any other incoming connections; it doesn't know that the connection from your target should be associated with your Tor connection, and it has no way to let that communication be opened in reverse like that to you.

Comment: In order to receive a connection back, you would need to use a tor hidden service, which requires Tor connectivity on both client and server, and meterpreter has to use a socks5 proxy to access the tor network. Alternatively, you can use a free http to onion redirector, such as onion.to, but you can only use reverse-http(s), and on the server, you have to use a reverse proxy that filters the extraneous stuff left by the proxy, like "This is the onion.to proxy" or something like that.